# Help on solving roots given sum of zeros, product of zeros, sum of coefficients are equal.

Tags: roots

The sum of zeros, the product of zeros, and the sum of the coefficients of the function f(x) = ax^2 +bx +c are equal. Show that all three of these quantities must equal a.

Pls help for school assignment.

Comment: Hint: [Vieta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Comment: What have you tried so far? What relationships do you have between the sums and products of the roots and the coefficients?

Comment: r+s=b/a
rs=c/a
r+s=a

However, if you make a=b/a, you get an imaginary number for the answer of a, so I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

Sum of zeros $= \frac{-b}{a}$ ( I think you made a mistake at this step)

product of zeros $=\frac{c}a$

Hence $c=-b.$

Hence $a+b+c=a+b-b=a$

Comment: However, r+s=-b/a, then -b/a = a. Thus, -b=a^2 and a = imaginary

Comment: But I feel like your answer is the best - love you

Comment: hmm... $b$ can be negative right? Hence $-b$ could be positive.